# Lenovo S920 repeatedly shuts itself off and back on by itself

Tags: reboot

I just bought a Lenovo S920, new set about a week ago. It's been turning itself off and back on every single day since the second day I bought it, at least once or twice **every one hour.**

An information that might help you figure this out for me, on the second day I downloaded every app I needed & packed about 70% of the phone storage, plus about 50% of my 32GB microSD. Also, my phone has 4GB Internal storage.

Does it have to do with those apps and tonnes of audio/video files? And ultimately, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As that behaviour started when you installed all that stuff, it at least suggests a relation. It could be one of the apps causing this; the audio/video files are unlikely to be the culprit.

I'd suggest you factory-reset the device and start over, but do not install all apps at once; instead only install one at a time and see if all stays stable before continuing with the next.

Once the trouble starts over, uninstall the last app you've installed and see if that cures it; if so, skip that app and continue with the next on your list. If all stays stable then, you know which app is problematic: contact its dev for further advice then.

---

A helpful thing to investigate *before* going the "hard way" described above is to "debug" the issue. As you didn't state which Android version your device is running, I will describe an approach that should work for most versions:

You need ADB on your computer (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) for how to achieve that), and connect your device via USB. Then start `adb logcat -v time -f debug.log` from your computer's command shell. Let it run.

As soon as the device reboots, stop the logcat task. Now check `debug.log` from bottom to top to see what initiated the reboot. If you have trouble reading/interpreting it, upload the log and add a link to your question, so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just take it to the authorized service centre and they will fix it. My Lenovo S920 USB connection did not work and in service centre they fixed it saying that the "soldering" of the port disconnected. They corrected it in one hour time. So there could be chance in your on/off switch too. So check with service centre and its safe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my S920 one year back in Jan 2014. It kept restarted itself every hour or so. Though I did not have too much installed on it, I pinned down the problem to the firmware update S114_130626. A restore back to the original S110_130515 worked for me.

However, now that much of my internal storage is being consumed, I notice that it sometimes (once or twice a week) restarts itself. So, perhaps it could be the full utilisation of the internal storage that is causing the problem.